# Calculate Numbers of hours worked from 10 duration value in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have 10 records in my database with start time and end time. I was able to calculate the duration value with SUBTRACT function. Now i am running  a loop and i want to calculate total numbers of hours worked from the duration value(or start and end value).

I tried AddHours and Add function but its giving error.Not sure i am using it correct or not.

```
Datetime TotalHours = TotalHours.add(Duration)

Datetime TotalHours = TotalHours.addHours(Duration)
```

this what i did.Gives conversion error.

I tried writing a function which manually calculate time by adding 60 minutes to hours and son on but there must be a easier way to do it.

Comment: What is `TotalHours` and `Duration` exactly? And since C# is case sensitive, they are probably `Add` and `AddHours`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Duration` is a `TimeSpan`:

```
var durations = ....
var total = new TimeSpan();
foreach (var duration in durations) // assuming durations is a collection of all the durations you have calculated
     total = total.Add(duration);

Console.WriteLine(total.Hours); // "whole" hours, try TotalHours for fractional

Console.WriteLine((int)total.TotalHours); // whole amount of total hours, ie 1 day + 3 h = 27 h
```

Comment: thats works fine but there is one small issue. So when total hours exceed more then 24 then it gives me value as 1.03:00:00, which is one day.three ours:zero mins:zero Secs. Now i did the splits string and able to display the total hours by 1*24 hours plus 3 hours, but was wondering is there any way in above code we can do that? Thanks.

Comment: (Convert.ToInt32(total.TotalHours) + ":" + Convert.ToInt32(total.Minutes)).ToString(); this worked!. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an instance of `TimeSpan` to accumulate all the durations.

For example:

```
var durations = // Your collection of TimeSpan items goes here.

var totalDuration = new TimeSpan();

foreach (var duration in durations)
    totalDuration += duration;

double totalHours = totalDuration.TotalHours; // Note: Includes fractional hours.
```

Comment: Thanks! you have the same solution as flindeberg. in the end i am converting total hours in string to display so didnt required to convert it into double.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say you want the No of Hours. [Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `Timespan` has a property [Hours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will give you the number of hours passed.

```
var TotalHours = Duration.Hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TimeSpan class, for example:

```
public class FromTo
{
    public DateTime From {get; set;}
    public DateTime To {get; set;}
    //other properties of your class
}
```

Now get the list of your objects with start and end dates. After that you can add result in loop:

```
public TimeSpan CalculateWorkTime(List<FromTo> fromto)
{
    TimeSpan sum = new TimeSpan();
    fromto.ForEach(p => 
    {
        sum += (p.To - p.From);
    });
    return sum;
}
```

Tell me if it works. Regards ;)